# can any one solve that sql problem please?

Tags: php, mysql

can any one solve that sql problem please?
ex: i have library system project

table 1 for all items

```
id  title  item_tybe  volume_id
1   php    book       null
2   asp    magazine   1
2   perl   magazine   2
```

table 2 for volume which have related with table 1 but with magazine only

```
id  volume  approved
1   vol1    yes
1   vol2    no
```

i want get all items (book - magazine ) but i want get magazine which her volume approved = yes

should i should if condition ?? i dont know how please help

Comment: Why are the id fields not unique?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant you ONLY want to get magazines that are approved, whilst getting all books:

```
SELECT title, item_type
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.volume_id = table2.id AND table2.approved = 'yes'
```

Let me know if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title, item_type FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON volume_id = table2.id
WHERE approved IS NULL or approved = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select * 
from table_1 t1
left join table_2 t2 on t1.volume_id=t2.id and t2.approved='yes'
```